# "contenteditable" attribute doesn't work when element added via "[innerHTML]" in Angular

Tags: html, angular, dom, attributes

I have met an unexpected behavior for me of `contenteditable` attribute in Angular. I have an object with HTML, stored as a value:

```
public json_html = {
  "button1":"<p contenteditable='true'>first section</p>",
  "button2":"<p>second section</p>",
  "button3":"<p>third section</p>",
}
```

And I apply this values like this (via `innerHTML`):

```
<div [innerHTML]="selectedButton"></div>
```

Everything works fine except `contenteditable` attribute - it's just missed in HTML:

[image]

**QUESTION:**

How to force `contenteditable` attribute to work (when element becomes through `[innerHTML]`)? Is there a proper way to do that or may be there is a workaround?

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pyhg3-lnivvj?file=app%2Fbutton-overview-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That attribute is stripped for security reasons

If you tell Angular that it should treat it as safe, use `DomSanitizer`

```
  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.json_html =  {
    "button1": sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<p contenteditable='true'>first section</p>"),
    "button2":"<p>second section</p>",
    "button3":"<p>third section</p>",
  }
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pyhg3-jbairw)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: can you tell me what DomSanitizer will do? or any reference link would be useful. @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: It wraps the value in a `SafeHtml` object, which is the marker for Angular to treat the value as safe. https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: can we add that html line in html `<div [innerHTML]="selectedButton"></div>` instead of the json, it will become complicated for me

Comment: You can use a pipe like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding/41089093#41089093

Comment: I mean to say, the code which we added in json `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml`  , can we add this in `home.html` , that will make my life easier

Comment: i was trying the same thing by creating a pipe but could not implement  :(

Comment: Does the pipe from stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding/… not work for you? Can you please update the stackblitz example to demonstrate the problem?